# Creating a deep convolutional neural network model in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm trying to create a 2D convolutional neural network with the following layers:

Conv2d => Activation => Conv2d => Activation => Max Pooling => Conv2d => Activation => Conv2d => Activation => Max Pooling => Fully connected hidden layer => Output layer

I tried to define the following CNN class for this purpose, but I get the following error when I run my train function:

```py
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x2048 and 128x512).
```

I think the dimensions of my class are initialized incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to compute the right dimensions. My model is created by executing the line `modelDeeper = CNN(deeper=True).to(device).` I think all that's needed to debug my code is to fix my CNN class so that the layers use the right dimensions.

Here is my CNN class:

```py
class CNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,dropout = 0, silu = False, numHidden = 1, deeper = False):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 5, padding='same')
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 5, padding='same')
        self.convDeeper1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3, padding='same')
        self.convDeeper2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3, padding='same')

        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*8*8,512)
        self.fcDeeper1 = nn.Linear(128, 512) # not sure why the input dimension should be 128
        
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 10)
        self.dropoutMaxPool = nn.Dropout(0)
        self.dropoutFC = nn.Dropout(0)
        if dropout != 0:
          self.dropoutMaxPool = nn.Dropout(0.25)
          self.dropoutFC = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.silu = silu
        self.numHidden = numHidden
        self.deeper = deeper

    # Note: F.silu applies the sigmoid linear unit activation function elementwise while F.relu applies the rectified linear unit activation function
    # elementwise.

    # x must be a tensor
    def activation(self, x):
      if not self.silu:
        return F.relu(x)
      else:
        return F.silu(x)

    # note: in this forward function, x is a tensor, and we apply operations to x in a specific order according to the layers of the CNN.
    # first we apply the convolution neural net. 
    def forward(self, x):
        if not self.deeper:
          x = self.activation(self.conv1(x))
          x = self.pool(x) # max pool layer
          x = self.dropoutMaxPool(x) # insert 

          x = self.activation(self.conv2(x))
          x = self.pool(x) 
          x = self.dropoutMaxPool(x)

        else:
          x = self.activation(self.convDeeper1(x))
          x = self.pool(x) # max pool layer
          x = self.dropoutMaxPool(x) # insert 

          x = self.activation(self.convDeeper2(x))
          x = self.pool(x) 
          x = self.dropoutMaxPool(x)

          x = self.activation(self.convDeeper2(x))
          x = self.pool(x) # max pool layer
          x = self.dropoutMaxPool(x) # insert 

          x = self.activation(self.convDeeper2(x))
          x = self.pool(x) 
          x = self.dropoutMaxPool(x)

        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        
        x = self.activation(self.fcDeeper1(x)) # does this use rectified linear units? This is the hidden fully connected layer.
        x = self.dropoutFC(x)
        
        

        x = F.log_softmax(self.fc2(x), 1) # for the output
        return x
```

If necessary, I can share a brief summary of the entire process used to generate the error I mentioned at the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect your model you will notice that the shape of your tensor before the `fcDeeper1` layer depends on your spatial dimensions. For example, for an input shape of `(batch_size, 3, 128, 128)`, it will have a shape of `(batch_size, 2048)`. This is because you are flattening the dimensions with `x = torch.flatten(x, 1)`.

One way to fix this without much hassle is to either have a fixed input dimension and set the `in_features` argument on `fcDeeper1` to the correct value, or use [lazy module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.modules.lazy.LazyModuleMixin.html), in your case [`nn.LazyLinear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html).

```
self.fcDeeper1 = nn.LazyLinear(out_features=512)
```